# Using a dropdown list with blazorise datagrid

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor and I am trying to create a datagrid that is editable. I have a column that requires a drop down list and when I click that item, it should pull a list down. I have that working, however, it doesnt keep the selected value when I click it. I just stays on the default. Is there any way to do this?

my datagrid column:

```
   <DataGridColumn TItem="CarTable" Field="@nameof(CarTable.ManualOrAutomatic)" Caption="Status" Editable >
          <EditTemplate>
    <Dropdown Visible="true" >
    <DropdownToggle>
        Select transmission
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem>Manual</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownDivider />
        <DropdownItem>Automatic</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
        </EditTemplate>
      </DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

`EditTemplate` cascades a `CellEditContext` object that you can use to update cell's value. You need to set `CellEditContext.CellValue` when `DropdownItem` is clicked:

```
<Dropdown Visible="true">
    <DropdownToggle>
        @(!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)context.CellValue) ? context.CellValue : "Select transmission")
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem Clicked="@(() => context.CellValue = "Manual")">Manual</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownDivider />
        <DropdownItem Clicked="@(() => context.CellValue = "Automatic")">Automatic</DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

Assuming ManualOrAutomatic property is string. If it's other type update the code accordingly.

More info about DataGrid cell templates: https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/templates

Comment: It works! however, the dropdown list stays on the "Select Transmission" toggle even though you pick an option...

Comment: Yes, you have to also change the text inside `DropdownToggle` based on the CellValue. I edited my answer.

Comment: For some reason, it returns a missing ; error... there shouldn't be one though, should there? I also apologize for being such a noob about this... blazorise is so confusing at this stage

Comment: That's my bad, I edited answer second time because first edit was incorrect. Could you check again?

Comment: @Dimiris Maragkos, still the same error... sorry for the delayed reply

Comment: I say cannot convert lambda expression to delegated return type

Comment: I added a cast to `string` for `context.CellValue`: `!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)context.CellValue)`.

Comment: Hah! that worked! you are a life saver! do you have any guide or documentation I could read to learn more?

Comment: Official Blazorise docs is what I mostly use: https://blazorise.com/docs/extensions/datagrid/templates